# Is the dual to $C^1[0,1]$ separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, separable-spaces

$C^1[0,1]$ is endowed with the norm $\|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f| + \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f'| $. I need to check if its dual $(C^1[0,1])^*$ is separable (I hope it is not). I am asking for the answer and the idea of proof.

Comment: You could try to use the fact that $C^1([0,1])$ has a continuous and dense embedding in $L^1(0,1)$, then pass to the duals, the dual of $L^1$ is $L^{\infty}$ which is not separable, maybe from this you can deduce that the dual of $C^1([0,1])$ is not separable either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\in[0,1]$ define $\lambda_x\in(C^1)^*$ by $\lambda_x f=f'(x)$.

If $x\ne y$ you can construct $f$ with $|f|\le1$, $|f'|\le 1$, $f'(x)=1$ and $f'(y)=0$. Hence $$||\lambda_x-\lambda_y||\ge1/2\quad(x\ne y)...$$